# Proof involving supremum

Tags: real-analysis

There is an exercise I want to prove:

Suppose that $\sup(A\cup B)=u$ where $A$ and $B$ are two bounded sets of real numbers. Suppose also that there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $a<u-\epsilon$ for all $a\in A$. Prove that $\sup(A\cup B)=\sup B$.

I know that $\sup(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$, so it is enough to show in the exercise that $\sup(A\cup B)=\sup B$, so all I need to show is that $\sup A\leq\sup B$. I assumed in my attempt, by contradiction, of course, that $\sup A>\sup B$. Here is what I have done. I know that there might be some mistakes in there, but I want to learn from them:
[image]

I also know that there is such $\epsilon\ $ that satisfies the given property, but I cannot determine what is $\epsilon\ $. Can you help me out giving me some hints? I will appreciate any suggestions or help from anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Argue that there exists $b\in B$ such that $u-\epsilon < b< u$. It follows that $a<b$ for all $a\in A$. This means $b$ is an upper bound for $A$, and therefore $\sup A\le b$. But $b\le \sup B$, and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all prove $u$ is an upper bound of $B$.  That's easy.  $B \subset A \cup B$.  So since $u$ is an upper bound of $A\cup B$ then for all $b \in B \subset A\cup B$ we have $b \le u$ so $u$ is an upperbound.

Now just prove it is the least upper bound.  That is if $w < u$ then there is a $b \in B$ so that $w < b \le u$.  Well, let $w' = \max(w, u -\epsilon) < u$.  Because as $u = \sup (A\cup B)$ that means there is an element of $v \in A\cup B$ so that $w' < v \le u$.  But if $v \in A$ we'd have $v < u-\epsilon$ so $v \not \in A$.  But $v \in A\cup B$ so $v\in B$.